# populate the master-detail table at the same time from JPA

Tags: jpa

I have a bidirectional entity similar like the one in hibernate example:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

Now I need save all the records into 2 tables through a JSON like this:

```
{
  "TroopName": "ABC", 
  "Soldiers": [{"Name":"Jack", "Age": "40"}, {"Name":"TOM", "Age": "30"}]
}
```

It will insert 1 record in the troop table and 2 records in soldier table which works fine. The only problem is in the soldier the foreign key is missing. I think it might relate to the troop.Id is not generated when the soldier table get populated. How can I populate this id to the soldier then?

I am using spring mvc + spring roo + json support

Comment: Could you show us how you set the `Troop` reference in the `Soldier` object in Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer: The problem is Spring Roo generating the AspectJ code to setup the soldiers without setting the back reference (although I already specified that it's a bidirectional relationship). So I have to add it myself.

```
public void Troop.setSoldiers(Set<Soldier> soldiers) {
    this.soldiers= soldiers;  // spring roo only generate this line!

    // I add the following segment:
    for(Soldier soldier: soldiers) {
        soldier.setTroop(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you inform the generator about a bidrectional relation? JPA only knows about two unidirectional and, the last time I checked (which admittedly was some time ago), Roo wasn't different in this aspect, the reference integrity was at the programmers level like in raw JPA.